# How pointers work in a function in C - Pointer to integer without a cast

Tags: c, pointers

I am currently practicing using pointers for an upcoming exam and am running through a few practice questions to brush up on them. I want to make my own version of the strrchr function with the given function signature:

```
char* mystrrchr(char*s, int c) {
```

And the main field:

```
int main(void) { 
    char* s = "ENCE260"; 
    char* foundAt = mystrrchr(s, 'E'); 
    if (foundAt == NULL) { 
        puts("Not found"); 
    } 
    else { 
        printf("%zd\n", foundAt - s); 
    } 
}
```

And I want the code to work without any changes to the main and function signature.

I want to return the index of the last time the character c appears in a string s as an integer. The jist of the code is fine, I just am unsure how to use the pointers correctly in this situation to return the desired output. For reference the error I am receiving is that I am making a pointer from integer without a cast.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <assert.h>

char* mystrrchr(char*s, int c) { 
    int position;
    int len = strlen(s);
    int i = 0;
    while (i < len) { 
        if (c == s[i]) { 
            position = i;
            i++; 
        } 
        else {
            i++;
        }
    } 
    return position; 
}

int main(void) { 
    char* s = "ENCE260"; 
    char* foundAt = mystrrchr(s, 'E'); 
    if (foundAt == NULL) { 
        puts("Not found"); 
    } 
    else { 
        printf("%zd\n", foundAt - s); 
    } 
}
```

That is my code thus far.

Comment: You function says it returns a char *, but you are returning an integer.

Comment: The difference between two pointers has the type `ptrdiff_t` and the correct length modifier for that is `t`, as in `%td`.  See POSIX [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html), although that aspect of it is common with the C99 standard (and C11).

Comment: For what it's worth... post-college assignment, you should almost never write your own `<string.h>` functions.  The versions in any `libc` worth using are optimized very well, and the only way you're likely to do better is if you know something special about your input.

Answer (score 1):

First you could change

```
char*mystrrchr(char*s, int c) { 
    ...
    return position; 
}
```

to

```
char*mystrrchr(char*s, int c) { 
    ...
    return s + position; 
}
```

because the first version returns the *relative* position.

Then you also need to initialize `position`:

```
char*mystrrchr(char*s, int c) { 
    int position = -1;
    ...
}
```

And then return `NULL` if nothing was found:

```
char*mystrrchr(char*s, int c) { 
    int position = -1;
    ...
    if(position == -1) return NULL;
    else return s + position;
}
```

At this point the function works correctly.
But you could improve the performance by using

```
while (s[i] != '\0')
```

instead of using `strlen`, as Jonathan Leffler pointed out in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Define `mystrrchr` as `int mystrrchr` and call `int foundAt = mystrrchr(`. Then `printf("%d\n", foundAt)`.

Comment: Looking at the code, this is not enough. Hint: consider what happens if `c` does not occur in the string.

Comment: Initialization `int position = -1` which means "no such char".

Answer (score 0):

```
char* mystrrchr(char*s, int c) {
   if ( s == NULL ) return NULL;
    char *position = NULL;
    int i = 0;
    while (s[i] != '\0' ) { 
        if (c == s[i]) { 
            position = &s[i];
        } 
        i++;
    } 
    return position; 
}
```

You can also go backwards:

```
char* mystrrchr2(char*s, int c) {
    if ( s == NULL ) return NULL; 
    char *position = NULL;
    int i = strlen(s) - 1;
    while (i > -1) { 
        if (c == s[i]) { 
            position = &s[i];
        break;
        } 
        i--;
    } 
    return position; 
}
```

Comment: Using `strlen()` scans the string twice.  In this context, you should not use `strlen()` and should have `while (s[i] != '\0')` as the loop condition.

Comment: You never look at `s[0]`. The loop condition should be `i >= 0`.